# Позиционирование елеммента не получается

Tags: html, css

[image: вот как выглядит]

уже запарился менять значения relative и absolute туда и обратно. Но нужно что бы выпадающий список был поверх всех элементов. Что бы он был кликабельным.

[проект](http://bot.immo/realty/?type=advanced&section=sale#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для контейнера, внутри которого находится форма, добавте `position: relative; z-index: 2;`, [скрин](http://joxi.ru/nAy816ksLLwW2Z)
Т.е. у контейнера класс `section-content`, но нужно добавить класс модификатор, т.к. этот класс используется и в других блоках.

Comment: спасибо, мозг просто отключился и забыл за этот контейнер.